# Office 2013 free upgrade offer with "multi-user" Office 2010 license

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, license, microsoft-office-2013

I have *3 user* Office 2010 license which I activated after October 19, 2012. So, I am eligible for [Office 2013 free upgrade offer](http://office.com/offer). But, I have some questions regarding multi-user license:

Will the upgrade offer give me *3 user* license of Office 2013?
Or, Do all 3 users need to go thru the process & get 3 single user licenses?

Comment: Since the offer is for Office 365 Home Premium you get access to 5 licenses.  A single license of Office 2013 is limited to a single computer.

Comment: @Ramhound With offer, one can get Office 2013 license too. See [Office.com/offer](http://office.com/offer).

Comment: I convered both possabilities for a reason.  Your conversation with Microsoft only confirmed what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after chatting with MS customer support: The offer gives single user license of Office 2013 and it doesn't overwrite previous license (its not an upgrade). One can continue to use old Office 2010 licenses.

Here's the chat transcript:

> You are now chatting with 'Steven M'.
>
> **Steven M:** Thank you for contacting Microsoft Store Chat!  How can I
>   help you today?
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** I have 3 user Office 2010 license which I activated after
>   October 19, 2012. If I upgrade it to Office 2013 with the offer, would I
>   get 3 user Office 2013 license? Or, each 3 users need to go thru the
>   process to get 3 single user licenses?
>
> **Steven M:** You will get a new Office 2013 licence for 1 Machine
>
> **Steven M:** Please see the link bellow for all the details and terms
>
> **Steven M:** [Office 2013 terms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/offer/pre-launch-offer-details-and-terms-FX102902434.aspx?redir=0)
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** Would all 3 users be eligible for offer?
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** I have seen the terms, but there's no mention of
>   multi-user license there..
>
> **Steven M:** So do you have 3 different product keys for Office 2010?
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** No. I have one product key which is valid for 3 users.
>
> **Steven M:** Then you will benefit from 1 Office 2013
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** Means, my 3 user license would be trimmed down to 1
>   user license. Right? or, other 2 users can continue to use Office
>   2010?
>
> **Steven M:** No, you will have 3 Office 2010 and 1 Office 2013
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** Unable to understand. Are you saying the free upgrade
>   doesn't overwrite the previous license?
>
> **Steven M:** No, it gives you an extra product key for Office 2013, it's
>   not an upgrade
>
> **Sachin Shekhar:** Ok. Thanks.
>
> **Steven M:** Thank you for chatting with us at Microsoft Store. We highly
>   appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to upgrade to Windows 10.  When I did my Office Pro 2010 will open but only for 5 move days.  I have lost my product key.  This solution is only go for one PC.